# What service should I use to process my files in a Cloud Storage bucket and upload the result?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

I have a software that process some files. What I need is:

- start a default image on google cloud (I think docker should be a good solution) using an API or a run command
- download files from google storage
- process it, run my software using those downloaded files
- upload the result to google storage
- shut the image down, expecting not to be billed anymore

What I do know is how to create my image hehe. But I can't find any info saying me what google cloud service should I use or even if I could do it like I'm thinking. I think I'm not using the right keywords to find what i need.

I was looking at Kubernetes, but i couldn't figure out how to manipulate those instances to execute a one time processing.

[EDIT]

Explaining better the process I have an app that receive images and send it to Google storage. After that, I need to process that images, apply filters, georeferencing, split image etc. So I want to start a docker image to process it and upload the results to google cloud again.

Comment: Why do you think you need to start an image? You should probably explain more about what your task is trying to do, what kind of processing you're doing, and then given the requirements or constraints someone can give a more informed answer otherwise its just guessing.

Comment: Ok, I made an edit. Maybe it is more clear now. Thanks

Comment: I provided an answer, which sounds like you can totally avoid using a server or VM altogether based on your edit.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using any of the [runtimes supported by Google Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#runtimes), they are easiest way to do those kind of operations (i.e. fetch something from Google Cloud Storage, perform some actions on those files and upload them again). The Cloud Functions will be triggered by an event of your choice, and after the job, it will die.

Next option in terms of complexity would be to deploy a [Google App Engine application in standard environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/). It allows you to deploy your own application written in [any of the supported languages](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/appengine-generation) for this environment. While there is traffic in your application, you will have instances serving, but the number of instances running can go down to 0 when they are not serving, which would mean less cost.

Another option would be [Google App Engine in flexible environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/). This product allows you to deploy your application in any custom runtime. This option has always at least one instance running, so it would never shut down.

Lastly, you can use [Google Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/) to "create and run virtual machines on Google infrastructure". Otherwise than GAE, this is not that managed by Google, which means that most of the configuration is up to you. In this case, you would need to programmatically indicate your VM to shut down after you have finished your operations.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your edit where you stated that you already have an app that is inserting images into Google Cloud Storage, your easiest option would be to use Cloud Functions that are triggered by additions, changes, or deletions to objects in Cloud Storage buckets.

You can follow the [Cloud Functions tutorial for Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/storage) to get an idea of the generic process and then implement your own code that handles your specific tasks. There are other tutorials like the [Imagemagick tutorial for Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/imagemagick) that might also be relevant to the type of processing you intend to do.

Cloud Functions is probably your lightest weight approach. You could of course do more full scale applications, but that is likely overkill, more expensive, and more complex. You can write your processing code in Node.js, Python, or Go.

Comment: I took a look at Cloud functions, but what i discover is that I cannot customize the VM. Actually I forgot to mention that part on question, sorry. I need a VM with high mem and at least 4 cores. What I'm trying to do is create an instance using compute API, run a docker inside it with my algorithm, and then i must shut it down. Now Im planing how would I shut the instance down from inside the docker, right after my algorithm.

Comment: You should really explain in more detail in your question exactly what you're trying to do and why you think you need a machine with those constraints. You could be making false assumptions that are going to cost you.